# Pass Id and String to WebAPI Get

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Im using the New MVC Web Api I have something like this:

```
    public class CustomersController : ApiController
    {
  public HttpResponseMessage Get()
        {
            //Return Somethings
        }
    }
```

I call it with /api/customers

now i want to be able to filter by nationality and id so i made this :

```
public class CustomersController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(int Id, String Nat)
    {
        //and i filter here Return Somethings
    }
}
```

if i try to use `/api/customers/1/us` it call the first method, i understand that these are query strings, so how do i define route so i can use `/api/customers/1/us` ?

Comment: /api/customers/1/us is an embedded value as opposed to a query string. 
Unfortunately I am not sure why it isn't calling the overloaded Get. Check the route maybe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
     name: "CustomersByIdAndNat",
     routeTemplate: "api/customers/{Id}/{Nat}/",
     defaults: new { controller = "Customers" }
);
```

And as a side note, `/1/us` is not the querystring. [Querystring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) is what it comes after `?` symbol on urls. For instance in your case, could be something like this

```
api/customers/?id=1&nat=us
```

Not saying you need to change the url format, just explaining the concept.